# How does this use of 'has been of no benefits' works? What is the grammar behind such expression?

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect

I have a piece of sentence where the use of 'of' in 'has been of' make it difficult to understand and to use:

The sentence is:

> "It is often argued that the act of sending a man to the moon **has been of** no benefits to the common people."

Could anyone explain it?

Comment: If something is useful, it is "of use".  If something is beneficial, it is "of benefit".  If something is helpful, it is "of help".  If it is useless, not beneficial, or not helpful:  *of no use, of no benefit, of no help*.

Comment: It looks like a typo.  It should say *of no benefit*.

Answer (score 2):

Good question, Fida! I found this great answer on http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst152029_You-ve-been--a--great-help.aspx

Standard form is:
**countable:**
You have been a great help.

**Uncountable**
You have been of help.
You have been of great help.

**You can't, in standard English, have the uncountable without a preposition.**
You have been help.

Answer (score 1):

In the example sentence, "has been" is the *present perfect continuous* conjugation of "to be," and "of no benefit" is a prepositional phrase. Grammatically, it's the same construct as sentences like "The cat has been on the table again," or "She has moved across the street.

Also, it should say "of no *benefit*" rather than "benefits." Consider substituting the plural in my two examples. "The cat has been on the tables again" makes sense if there are multiple tables. But "has moved across the *streets*" doesn't make sense. I'm not sure, but I noticed that in this case, "benefit" is uncountable - we can use phrases like *some benefit* or *little benefit* - whereas benefits, again in this case, is countable, meaning it is expressed in integers.

Comment: I was interested to know the placement of 'of' before 'no benefit'. It is little bit different from my understanding.
And why 'benefit', not its 'plural'!

Comment: @FidaHasan You are right, it should be "no benefits". The only singular number is *positive one*, even zero and negatives are plural.

Comment: @user178049 It should not be plural, benefit is correct.

Comment: @JamesP I would disagree with that, look at this [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/there-are-no-comments-there-is-no-comment)

Comment: @user178049 That's not the same. You could say, "there have been no benefits", but in this case it is "of no benefit".
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+no+benefit%2Cof+no+benefits&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20no%20benefit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20no%20benefits%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

My Question was about the Grammatical Structure in place of the use 'of'. I think, I have got the structure of it as following;
**"be + of + noun (abstract)"**

> *A form of "to be" followed by "of" and a noun is usually equivalent to "to be" followed by an adjective of similar meaning. It is an
>   idiomatic use of an "of" phrase. Here are some other examples. to be
>   of use = to be useful to be of help = to be helpful to be of
>   importance = to be important to be of significance = to be significant
>   to be of consequence = to be consequential to be of interest = to be
>   interesting to be of assistance = to be helpful (because there is no
>   word "assistanceful") to be of worth = to be valuable (because there
>   is no word "worthful") to be of good quality = to be good with respect
>   to quality (because there is no word "good-quality-ful")*

In above example,
*"It is often argued that the act of sending a man to the moon has been of no benefits to the common people."*
It seems it should be "has been of no benefit to the common people".

This is simply the present perfect of "is of no benefit to the common people".
"be of" is a substitute for "be" + an adjective, so the quoted expression is equivalent to "has not been beneficial to the common people".